# VirtualBox Windows GUEST can not "see" local Network

Tags: windows-7, networking, virtualbox

I've got VirtualBox set up on a Windows 7 HOST with Windows XP Guest.

Guest can access the Internet and Host, but not Network that the Host is on.

I'm using the default NAT networking in the Guest Settings.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

NAT networking will place the gusts in a virtual network, so yes they cannot see your internal network.

In order to make it work, you must stop using the NAT networking mode, and set it to bridged. To do NAT translations for the guests, edit your router or whatever device in your network does the NAT translations.

If you just want to access some shares, you can make driveletters on your HOST, and use the shared mappings feature to bring them to the GUEST.

Comment: If I have a Drive letter  X: on my Host and Share it,is it accessible in the Guest as X:  ?

Comment: It did not work that way, so, I had to assign a drive letter to the share.